# How to reduce the width of the Grid element in React with MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I reduce the width of the first Grid element in the Material UI, so that the other 3 elements fill the freed space equally?
[visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5cXB.png)

Should i change grid item's 'xl', 'lg', 'md', 'sm', 'xs' sizing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should first learn what those [grid props mean](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/). The `xs`, `md`, etc are referring to breakpoints, not just sizing. To strictly answer your question, you could change the number of columns and, and specify an appropriate `xs` value for each of them , e.g.:

```
<Grid container spacing={2} columns={14}>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <Item>Column 1</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Item>Column 2</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Item>Column 3</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Item>Column 4</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```